# Ultimate member logout not working using WPML

Tags: wordpress, caching, authentication, logout, wpml

I'm using `Ultimate member` with `WPML` and logout not working and when click on logout it redirects to again login where there is not login form rather than its showing user as login.

Scenario :

1) Login from login page

2) Logout from Logout page (Ultimate member built in logout page)

-> Still its showing user as login when he/she redirects after click on Logout page

Solutions Tried :

1) Removed Cache plugin
2) exclude Login and Logout page from cache using wp-rocket
3) Tried this solution using this Link : https://wpml.org/forums/topic/wpml-ultimate-member-login-logout-redirection-url-for-both-languages-i-use/

to use config file in `wpml configuration text` (used below code) :

```
<wpml-config>
  <admin-texts>
    <key name="um_cached_role_member">
      <key name="login_redirect_url"/>
      <key name="logout_redirect_url"/>
    </key>
  </admin-texts>
</wpml-config>
```

4) Tried this solution from this link : https://wpml.org/forums/topic/ultimate-member-logout-link-not-working-in-different-languages/

But in above `solution 4)` i don't know how to pass logout in `wpml text configuration` file

------>
**Above issue is resolved but now the only issue is that any action i perform not work until i hard refresh (ctrl + shift + R).**

Scenario of issue :

I login then on topbar there is menu for profile and Logout but now when i click on logo it redirects to home page with topbar display me login which is wrong because as i login already it should be profile and logout button.

But when i hard refresh (ctrl + shift + R) it works properly similarly when i walk to other page similar issue it doesn't work as expected till i hard refresh.

**Plugin Used are : Ultimate member,WPML,WP-rocket**

Comment: if you disable `wp-rocket` does everything work well?

Answer (score 2):

Just check in case, it is useful for others, I found that by changing under "WPML" > "Languages" > "Language URL format"

**For Example-**

from:
"Language name added as a parameter (hidden link - French) "

to:
"Different languages in directories (hidden link - English, hidden link - French) "

It all worked!

Comment: have tried this one from this solution : https://wpml.org/forums/topic/ultimate-member-logout-link-not-working-in-different-languages/ but no luck

Comment: please check the page on another browser for same.

Comment: upgrade the version after you can check for same

Comment: I'm using wpml and ultimate member pro versions and both are latest so there is no need to upgrade

Comment: If you have purchased the plugin then you try to ask the question to support system for your issue once.

Answer (score 1):

Might try to insert this in `functions.php` and tell what happens.

```
session_cache_limiter('none');
header('Cache-control: max-age='.60*60*24*365 .', public');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate(DATE_RFC1123,filemtime(__file__)));
header("Content-type: application/javascript;  charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: I think its caching issue for sure and when i pass query string to url then its working but still requires hard refresh(`ctrl + shift + R`) otherwise its not working

Comment: @raju_eww Please Post one comment, instead of multi-messaged.  Please use EDIT and remove extra comments.   

about caching, it could be because some plugins cache the pages. It need further digg into the problem, which I can't unfortunately. (

Answer (score -1):

is easy create new page and paste this sharecode [utimatemember_loggdout]. that is and good luck